# Numerical value of $\exp(1000 i \sqrt3 )$

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

Which numerical approximation of $\exp(1000 i \sqrt3 )$ is correct?

`-0.512025 - 0.85897i`  or  `-0.115162 + 0.993347i`

Could you argument your answer?

Comment: This is a somewhat odd question, since a simple computer calculation will yield the answer. Are you asking for a way to know the answer without a computer?

Comment: My problem is that, Mathematica returns first answer for N[E^(1000 I Sqrt[3])] and the second for N[(E^(1000 I ))^Sqrt[3]]. At this moment I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: http://imgur.com/3BQwIq6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have complex numbers, in general, the exponentials are multivalued and $\exp(ab) \ne \exp(a)^b$ when you consider the principal value.

For example, $\exp(2\pi i \sqrt 2) = \cos(2\pi\sqrt 2)+i\sin(2\pi\sqrt 2)$

But $\exp(2 \pi i )^\sqrt 2 = 1$

Hence you should not try to simplify $\exp(1000 i \sqrt 3)$ as $\exp(1000 i)^\sqrt 3$.